# dplyr divide column by a mean of some of its elements specified in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe:

```
df1 <- data.frame(site = c(rep("a", 6), rep("b", 6), rep("c", 6))
                  ,intensity = c(25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 20, 21, 22, 23, 22, 21, 19, 24, 31, 32, 33, 33, 35)
                  ,category = rep(c("up", "down", "nochange"), times = 6)
                  )
```

It looks like this:

```
     site intensity category  
[1]     a        25       up
[2]     a        26     down
[3]     a        27 nochange
[4]     a        28       up 
[5]     a        29     down 
[6]     a        20 nochange 
[7]     b        21       up 
[8]     b        22     down 
[9]     b        23 nochange 
[10]    b        22       up
[11]    b        21     down 
[12]    b        19 nochange 
[13]    c        24       up 
[14]    c        31     down 
[15]    c        32 nochange 
[16]    c        33       up 
[17]    c        33     down 
[18]    c        35 nochange
```

For each `site`, I want to calculate the `mean(intensity)`, but only for one category, `nochange`. And then subtract the value of this mean from all `intensity` values for that `site`. So, step by step, it would be:

1. `group_by(site)`
2. calculate `mean(intensity)` only for `category == "nochange`
3. divide `intensity` (of all `categories`) by the `mean(intensity)` value created in point 2

So, for my example `df1` , I will have 3 means: site a `mean = 23.5` , site b; `mean = 21`, site c; `mean = 33.5`

and my output `df_out` will look as follows:

```
     site   intensity category  
[1]     a         1.5       up
[2]     a         2.5     down
[3]     a         3.5 nochange
[4]     a         4.5       up 
[5]     a         5.5     down 
[6]     a        -3.5 nochange 
[7]     b         0.0       up 
[8]     b         1.0     down 
[9]     b         2.0 nochange 
[10]    b         1.0       up
[11]    b         0.0     down 
[12]    b        -2.0 nochange 
[13]    c        -9.5       up 
[14]    c        -2.5     down 
[15]    c        -1.5 nochange 
[16]    c        -0.5       up 
[17]    c        -0.5     down 
[18]    c         1.5 nochange
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After grouping by 'site', subset the `intensity` with a logical expression on the 'category', get the `mean` and subtract from the original 'intensity' values

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
   group_by(site) %>% 
   mutate(intensity = intensity - mean(intensity[category == "nochange"])) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 18 × 3
   site  intensity category
   <chr>     <dbl> <chr>   
 1 a           1.5 up      
 2 a           2.5 down    
 3 a           3.5 nochange
 4 a           4.5 up      
 5 a           5.5 down    
 6 a          -3.5 nochange
 7 b           0   up      
 8 b           1   down    
 9 b           2   nochange
10 b           1   up      
11 b           0   down    
12 b          -2   nochange
13 c          -9.5 up      
14 c          -2.5 down    
15 c          -1.5 nochange
16 c          -0.5 up      
17 c          -0.5 down    
18 c           1.5 nochange
```